# The constructor property - Relate Pre-existing Objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to test whether it's possible to make one object inherit from another object AFTER both objects have been created using literals.  I tried to aim the constructors and prototypes at one another but it seems like no matter what, the only way Im going to pull this off is by building a new object using one of the pre-existing ones..  Let me know if I'm wrong.  Here was my quick attempt to solve the problem.

```
Object.relate = function(parent, child){
    function F(){};
    F.prototype = parent;
    child.constructor = F;
}
alpha = {a:1};
beta = {b:2};

Object.relate(alpha, beta);
```

Comment: Does this work? Does it give you an error? What are you trying to achieve and where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `beta` can access properties defined on `alpha` by using `beta.constructor.prototype`.

When you use `new` on a function like

```
var obj = new F();
```

then `obj.__proto__` is automatically set to `F.prototype`. When you have already existing objects and you are not creating the object using `new` you must set the `__proto__` by yourself.

```
obj.__proto__ = F.prototype;
```

So in your example you need to call

```
child.__proto__ = parent;
```

**Resources:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto
- http://killdream.github.com//blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/index.html#sec-4-1

The problem is that now every browser expose the `__proto__` property. IE doesn't support it so you cannot create a browser-compatible solution without actually creating a new object and copying the properties.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  What I'm trying to get a grasp of is the Core Language.  Is __proto__ a standard object property or just something wired in by the browsers for ease?  If it doesn't exist outside of particular browsers then it isn't of much value to me.  However - if it does exist but is merely restricted from editing in IE, then I would find it interesting (but it sounds like a browser added property to me)

Comment: @Marlin: `__proto__` is not a part of standard and is not fully supported by every JS environment, but most of them use it. [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf) is a part of standard, but it only for read-only access to a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to work for me (tested in Chrome):

```
function relate(parent, child){
    child.__proto__ = parent;
}

alpha = {a:1};
beta = {b:2};

relate(alpha, beta);

console.log(beta.a);
```

Output: '1'.